# How to detect if the values in array are in a certain range and return a binary array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, range, ipython

So I am trying to detect if the values in an array is in a certain range and then return a binary logical array i.e. one for true and zero for false. I have this but iPython keeps complaining

```
D = ( 1 < X[0,:] + X[1,:]) < 2 ).astype(int)
```

the interesting thing is that just checking one way works totally ok

```
D = ( X[0,:] + X[1,:]) < 2 ).astype(int)
```

which I find a bit perplexing.

Comment: "I find a bit perplexing".  That is perplexing code.  Could you explain why you think this is sensible code?  What do you think this will do?

Comment: @S.Lott looks like X is a numpy array

Comment: @S.Lott your totally right. I thought that Python would magically understand that I wanted to find all values between one and two. I don't know what I was thinking. Obviously I was delirious after working too much...

Comment: Matlab for example would return an array of just ones since it evaluates left from right. Python thankfully tells you this is a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Y=X[0,:]+X[1,:]
D = ((1<Y) & (Y<2)).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
bit_array = map(lambda x: 1 < x < 5 and 1 or 0, array)
```

bit_array is [0, 1, 1, 1, 0] after that. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: replace map with list comprehension...    b = [1 < x < 5 and 1 or 0 for x in array]

Comment: Yes exactly! Interesting way of thinking, bit of a newbie at Python so I am still struggling with some concepts or ways of doing things. This seems quite powerful though.

Comment: I am loving this concept! I think will change my whole way of thinking.

Answer (score 1):

unutbu's is shorter, this is more explicit

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.logical_and(1 < np.arange(5), np.arange(5)< 4).astype(int)
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
 bits = [ bool(low <= value < high) for value in some_list ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `all` (edited to return `int`):

```
D = numpy.all([1 < x, x < 2], axis=0).astype(int)
```